# How to make a RadWindow responsive based on screen / viewport size using JavaScript and CSS Grid

Tags: javascript, css, telerik, css-grid, radwindow

I've been looking for a solution to make a Telerik RadWindow work responsively.  There are two things that need to be responsive, the contents in the RadWindow, and the RadWindow itself.

**Problem:**

Per [Telerik:](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radwindow-not-responsive-when-used-with-bootstrap)  "*RadWindow does not support responsive size change and it does not change size automatically according to the viewport, because the behavior in such a scenario cannot be strictly defined*"

Comment: Checkout this demo: http://kandoodev.com/autosizeradwindow.aspx .It will auto size the radwindow according to screen dimensions i.e. radwindow size will adjust to smaller screen sizes of mobile devices in an automated manner.

Comment: The first button in the link somewhat duplicates responsiveness, but doesn't center the RadWindow on the screen like the solution below.  The other two buttons did not duplicate responsiveness like the solution below.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: It does center as I have noticed. But, on a mobile phone if the address bar disappears while window is opened then your comment is correct. Smart phones have a feature of removing address bar suddenly. If you keep address bar on smartphone visible then it does center.

Comment: Try out this new demo:  http://www.kandoodev.com/autosizeradwindownew.aspx .It centers on android even when address bar has vanished.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**  *(The contents inside the RadWindow need to be responsive, as does the RadWindow itself)*

**RadWindow Contents:**
I used CSS Grid to make the contents of the RadWindow responsive in this example.

```
        .sectionSearch {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 3px;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
            align-items: end;
            max-width: 809px;
        }
```

**RadWindow Responsiveness:**

The viewport can be set to a percentage of the screen, per [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/set-radwindow-size-in-percent) article.  You can then use JavaScript media queries to adjust the percentages of the height and width of the viewport, depending on the size of the screen.

Using a combination and modification of a few posts, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739960/use-multiple-matchmedia-with-svg-for-responsive-viewbox-resizing) one, the following sample solution worked for my needs of making a RadWindow responsive.

```
          var $ = $telerik.$;
        var radwindow;

        function pageLoad() {
            radwindow = $find("<%= radwindow.ClientID%>");
        }

        $(window).resize(function () {
            if (radwindow.isVisible()) {
                setWindowsize();
            }
        });

        function setWindowsize() {

            //var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
            //var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

            /* ==================================================== */

            // media query event handler
            if (matchMedia) {
                var mqls = [ // array of media queries
                    window.matchMedia("(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 399px)"),
                    window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px)"),
                    window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px)"),
                    window.matchMedia("(min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1000px)"),
                    window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 4000px)")
                ]

                for (i = 0; i < mqls.length; i++) { // loop though media queries
                    mqls[i].addListener(WidthChange); // listen for queries
                    WidthChange(mqls[i]); // call handler func at runtime
                }
            }

            // media query change
            function WidthChange(mql) {

                if (mqls[0].matches) {
                    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
                    radwindow.setSize(Math.ceil(viewportWidth * 90 / 100), Math.ceil(viewportHeight * 90 / 100));
                } else if (mqls[1].matches) {
                    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
                    radwindow.setSize(Math.ceil(viewportWidth * 90 / 100), Math.ceil(viewportHeight * 60 / 100));
                } else if (mqls[2].matches) {
                    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
                    radwindow.setSize(Math.ceil(viewportWidth * 90 / 100), Math.ceil(viewportHeight * 40 / 100));
                } else if (mqls[3].matches) {
                    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
                    radwindow.setSize(Math.ceil(viewportWidth * 90 / 100), Math.ceil(viewportHeight * 40 / 100));
                } else if (mqls[4].matches) {
                    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
                    radwindow.setSize(Math.ceil(viewportWidth * 70 / 100), Math.ceil(viewportHeight * 45 / 100));
                }
            }
                radwindow.center();
            }
```